# Anonymous user in devise - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, registration, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to rails and I tried to make simple authentication with anonymous user. I followed [this](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/1679-lazy-user-registration-for-rails-apps/) tutorial and I have this error:

```
undefined method `find_or_initialize_by_token'
```

**This is my AnonymousUser model:**

```
class AnonymousUser < User
  ACCESSIBLE_ATTRS = [:name, :email]
  attr_accessible *ACCESSIBLE_ATTRS, :type, :token, as: :registrant
  def register(params)
    params = params.merge(type: 'User', token: nil)
    self.update_attributes(params, as: :registrant)
  end
end
```

**This is my User model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :recoverable,
    :rememberable, :registerable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :validatable,
    :token_authenticatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

And the last one important is my **ApplicationController** which has this error:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def authenticate_user!(*args)
    current_user.present? || super(*args)
  end

  def current_user
    super || AnonymousUser.find_or_initialize_by_token(anonymous_user_token).tap do |user|
      user.save(validate: false) if user.new_record?
    end
  end

  private
  def anonymous_user_token
    session[:user_token] ||= SecureRandom.hex(8)
  end
end
```

Someone told me that if AnonymousUser user inherits from User then AnonymousUser have method called `find_or_initialize_by_token`, but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: which rails version are you using?

Comment: rails 3.2.1. Is that good version for this method?

Answer (score 1):

Provided you have latest rails installed, try to refactor:

```
# in ApplicationController#current_user

AnonymousUser.find_or_initialize_by_token(anonymous_user_token).tap do |user|
  user.save(validate: false) if user.new_record?
end
```

to something like this:

```
AnonymousUser.safely_find(anonymous_user_token)
```

and push the `find_or_initialize_by_token` and `save(validate: false)` into the model.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the blog post you referenced, but today, I would use

```
AnonymousUser.where(anonymous_user_token: anonymous_user_token).first_or_initialize
```

Dynamic finders have been deprecated AFAIK.

However, @Saurabh Jain is absolutely correct in his suggestion to refactor that block into a nice little push-button class method on the AnonymousUser.